# execute code if textfield is NOT empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a simple text field that on my view controller. When it is empty I have the button below it hidden. I am trying to code it so when a user types in something that button below is unhidden.

I had a similar issue with a photograph fill in an image view. So i figured if i reused that code and changed a few things it would work, but it just stays hidden.

Here is the code i've used so far

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (self.buyerBrief.text != nil){
        continueButton.hidden = true
    } else {
        continueButton.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Based on answers and comments below I tried the following but still no luck

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (self.buyerBrief.text == "" || self.buyerBrief.text!.isEmpty){
        continueButton.hidden = true
    } else if (self.buyerBrief.text != ""){
        continueButton.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: But whether the text is `nil` is not the same as whether the text is empty.

Comment: Your new code is even worse, as the logic makes no sense plus it fails to cover every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. The text field's text can be non-`nil` but still empty. What you want to know is whether the text field's text is non-`nil` and then, if it is, whether it `isEmpty`.

Comment: I'm going to update my question with the new code i tried but still doesn't work. The button hides fine, but doesn't reappear

Comment: Also your new code is atrocious and is not at all what I suggested doing.

Comment: could you please show what you meant then

Comment: `b.hidden = tf.text == nil || tf.text!.isEmpty` is simplest - covers the whole thing in one little line